# How do I change the styles of some shared component in React and I have configured routes with react route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a web app that is consisted of few pages and have configured routes with react-route-dom. On the pages, I have some shared components and I want them to be styled differently on other pages except the Home page.

How do I get this done? Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if `pathname` is path of **home** or else not you can use `useLocation` to get the `pathname` and add conditional styling or classes.

[useLocation v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)
[useLocation v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location)

```
import React from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Common_Component=()=>{
const location=useLocation()
const pathname=location.pathname

return(
    <div>
        <div classes={pathname=="home"?"home_class":"other_class"}>
         ...
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Or

You can pass boolean props to the component to let component know it should use **home** bases classes or **other** classes.

PS.

- you will still need to do conditional check if props is `true` or `false`
- [useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-match) you can use `useMatch` to match the current url with `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is always good to share code, I would recommend creating a new component for the homepage. Otherwise you are coupling your components. What happens if you want to add another specialisation for the whatever-component? You add another case! Your components grow and wire up more and more until you have one big pot of spaghetti. Hence, it makes sense in many situations to just create a new component for a new use-case.